# find file type and sort by size and then delete

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have 1000s of directories inside a main directory and I would like to be able to find a certain type of file from inside the 1000s of directories, list the files by size and then delete the largest files with out deleting the directories they are in.

I suppose the delete command might be a follow on from the find command and not executed all in one.

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: how do you want to decide what files to delete, after you have seen the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find and list files without deleting them, open the terminal and type:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -name \*.ext
```

To find, list and delete files, use the command:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -name \*.ext -delete
```

where:

- `-size +1M` finds files larger than 1 Megabyte (unit of 1048576 bytes)
- `\*.ext -delete` deletes all files that have the extension `.ext`
- `-delete`  delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed, an  error message is issued. If `-delete` fails, find's exit status will be nonzero (when it eventually exits). Use of `-delete` automatically turns on the `-depth` option, which processes each directory's contents before the  directory  itself..

Comment: Works great @karel